# jqgrid change the font color of cell based on the value of another cell

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

how can we change the font colour of a column based on the value of another column value?

Suppose I have 2 columns, col1 and col2
if col1 has value 1 - col2 should be red in color
if col1 has value 2 - col2 should be green in color

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function fontFormatter(cellValue, opts, rowObject){ 
    switch(rowObject.col1){
        case "1": 
            return '<span style="color:red">'+cellValue+'</span>'; 
        break; 
        case "2" : 
            return '<span style="color:green">'+cellValue+'</span>'; 
        break; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `loadComplete`:

```
loadComplete: function() {
    var gridData = $("#GRID_ID").jqGrid('getRowData');

    for(var i=0; i<=gridData.length; i++) {
        var rowData = $("#GRID_ID").jqGrid('getRowData',i+1);

        if(rowData.col1 == 1) { 
            $("#GRID_ID").jqGrid('setCell',i+1,"col2","",{color:'red'});
        }   
        if(rowData.col1 == 2) { 
            $("#GRID_ID").jqGrid('setCell',i+1,"col2","",{color:'green'});
        }
    }
}
```

Tell me if it did (or not) work

Comment: I found solution using formatter....

function fontFormatter(cellValue, opts, rowObject){
            
            switch(rowObject.a_cashflowtype){                    
            case  "1":
                return '<span style="color:red">'+cellValue+'</span>';
                break;
            case  "2" :
                return '<span style="color:green">'+cellValue+'</span>';
                break;
            }
        }

Comment: Please post this comment as answer and thick it as an "accepted answer", so that people with the same problem as yours would find it

Comment: lucasdc I have added ita as answer